# How to get current absolute url in twig without rendering route?

Tags: symfony, twig

In twig I need to get the current full uri (url + uri ) without render it it like

```
path('route_test', {param1:1})
```

How to get it ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try to use :

```
{{ app.request.uri }}
```

Comment: Do not work anymore. Don't know what to use instead.

Comment: @Xdg try this: `{{ url('<current>') }}`

Answer (score 5):

As it was said above, some of the answers are not valid anymore.

What worked for me as of **2017'09** is this

```
{{ url('<current>') }}
```

Comment: You need to render it.

Comment: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "<current>" as such route does not exist.").

Answer (score 2):

In latest version of twig is not work anymore `{{app.request.uri}}`

Try `{{global.request.uri}}` instead.

Comment: Variable "global" does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You may have issues with subrequests (`$this->forward` from a controller or `{{ render(controller('...')) }}` from a view), I prefer using a Twig extension for this.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig\Extension;

// ...    

class MyExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    // ...

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('current_locale', [$this, 'currentLocale']),
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('current_uri', [$this, 'currentUri']),
        ];
    }

    public function currentLocale()
    {
        return $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest()->getLocale();
    }

    public function currentUri()
    {
        return $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest()->getUri();
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my';
    }
}
```